# iPhone - UITextView with html content?

Tags: iphone, html, input, uitextview, richtext

The `UITextView` has a method named `setContentToHTMLString` that displays html inside a `UITextView`.
But this is a private API and probably gets my app rejected by apple.

Is there any way around this to somehow set the content to an htm string without calling this method directly? or any other way to allow html content in a view that is editable (Keyboard accessible)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I absolutely loath the Three20 framework. It adds huge bulk to your apps, adds a ton of class categories that you probably don't need, multiplies your compiling time many times on a clean compile, and can cause issues if you accidentally don't set all of the sub-projects settings correctly -- personal horror story, I had an app update in the app store broken on all arm6 devices for 3 weeks after adding Three20 while Apple took their sweet time approving my simple fix.

Anyway, enough bashing on Three20. Here's another option if you want something much more compact that is a simple drop in replacement for UITextView with basic HTML support: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bctextview. I don't know if that one supports editing though. This one: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotextview supports rich text editing, but I'm not sure if it's in HTML format. They're both worth a look though to see if you can utilize them for your needs. I would only use Three20 as an absolute last resort, and then still probably wouldn't use it.

Comment: Can I use the keyboard to type in it? in the other words is it editable?

Comment: I downloaded it and it's a subclass of UIView and not UITextView so it doesn't allow typing. I don't see the point of this class since I can use a UIWebView instead.

Comment: The first one I believe is simply for viewing, however the EGOTextView is fully editable. Are you specifically looking for HTML support or just rich text editing? If just rich text, the EGOTextView should work fine for that.

Comment: I ended up using EGOTextView with some modifications

Comment: perfect just what I was looking for!

Comment: @aryaxt is EGOTextView support HTML?

Comment: @luyuan Yes it does, but it was full of bugs at a time I used it. I ended up spending 4-5 weeks learning the code and fixing bugs. If you are open to force your users to use iOS6 you could use the attributedString property of the UILabel. Apple finally decided to add rich text to UILabel :)

Comment: @aryaxt Thanks for your answer:) Is it possible to insert an image in it? btw: I couldn't find a method to set the html string in it. Could you plz kindly let me know? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @luyuan That was something I worked on in my previous job, I don't have access to the code anymore :( I might have created that method myself. https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/tree/master/Core/Source get the category named NSAttributedString+html, that would convert html to NSAttributedString, then you pass the attributed string to EGOTextView

Comment: @aryaxt Thx for your reply. Yes I have integrate DTCoreText and can convert html to NSAttributedString. But it seems can't display an image in EGOTextView.

Comment: @luyuan Sorry I haven't tried to display an image in EGOTextView. IT suppose to be a rich text editor, I don't think it supports images

Comment: @aryaxt Finally i use KindEditor to edit HTML. Really thx for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I know to what you are asking are `TTStyledText` and `TTStyledTextLabel`, two classes from the [Three20 framework](http://three20.info/) that allows you to treat HTML content. They only support a limited subset of HTML, though, so I don't know if this fit your needs.

If you simply want to display/edit some unformatted text taken from the web, have a look at: [`+stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score -3):

[UITextView setValue:textString forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];

Comment: This metode is undocumented. Application is accepted on appstore with this?

Comment: DO NOT use this method. It is undocumented and your app will surely get rejected from apple.